# Laravel 5.2 env encoding

Tags: laravel-5

I use the forget password package. The settings file is \config\mail.php. Things work fine.

But then I change the setting to .env, the characters are wrong, garbled.
Actually, 4 Chinese characters, 2 are normal, 2 are garbled.

**.env**

```
FROM_NAME=通天教主
```

**\config\mail.php**

```
'from' => ['address' => env('FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => '通天教主'], //normal

'from' => ['address' => env('FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => env('FROM_NAME')], //garbled

'from' => ['address' => env('FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => mb_convert_encoding(env('FROM_NAME'), "UTF-8", "Big5")], //garbled

'from' => ['address' => env('FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => mb_convert_encoding(env('FROM_NAME'), "UTF-8", "auto")], //garbled
```

I checked with notepad++, the two files are utf8 without BOM.
Apache server : VirtualHost: addDefaultCharset UTF-8
PHP php.ini : default_charset = "UTF-8"

Then I tried to echo at the bigging of \config\mail.php, detect its encodeing

**\config\mail.php**

```
<?php

$str = env('FROM_NAME') . "\r\n";
echo mb_detect_encoding(env('FROM_NAME'));

exit;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    ... ...
    ... ...
```

It's utf8, but also garbled.

Is it possible that this is because of Windows + xampp? Any resolution?

Comment: try `FROM_NAME='通天教主'`

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `env()` is dependent on system active code page. Try `getenv()` instead.

Comment: don't comments on answer section